# Retrieving email address with Facebook sdk 4.4.0 for Android

Tags: android, facebook

Anyone noticed that Facebook sdk 4.4.0 is not returning the email address when performing a successful login with the following permissions: "email", "public_profile", like this:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
```

and on success executing this snippet:

```
GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
        String email = user.optString("email");
        String userId = user.optString("id");

    }
}).executeAsync();
```

This is a real pain, the docs are not so nice with me. Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: You need to ask for the email field if you want it

Comment: @WizKid, check the full description of the problem. Also, for those who don't check the full description, please check the code snippets.

Comment: You are not asking for the email field

Comment: @WizKid. can you please post a solution. Me too having this issue.

Comment: I told the solution. You need to ask for the email field if you want it

Comment: @WizKid can you throw a snippet here? Also can you explain that why is this same piece of code returning the email address?

Comment: In API v2.4 you need to specify the fields you need. So the code works in old version of the API but not in v2.4 and later

Comment: did you find a solution for this? @WizKid could you please tell us exactly how it should work?

Comment: Look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4 and specifically Declarative Fields